# Update Input field value with javascript

Tags: javascript, input, microtime

I am trying to build a javascript function that will update an input field every second with a new number. This is essentially what I'm hoping my function can do, and hopefully someone can give me a pointer about what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script>
   var myVar = setInterval(function(){ getNumber() }, 1000);

   function getNumber() {
     var x = round(microtime(true) * 1000);;
     document.getElementById("displaynum").value = x;

</script>

<input type="text" id="displaynum">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues you have:

- Closing bracket for the function
- It is `Math.round()` and not just `round()`
- What is `microtime()`? I have replaced it with `Math.random()` to generate a random number.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  getNumber()
}, 1000);

function getNumber() {
  var ts = new Date().getTime();
  var x = Math.round(ts*Math.random());
  document.getElementById("displaynum").value = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="displaynum">
```

**Update:**

Use `new Date().getTime()` to get the current time stamp and couple it with `Math.random()` to get a random number with least probability to get repeated.

Comment: Those are great points, thanks! Good code. I was using microtime(), which is a php function, to continuously track time so I never generate a duplicate number...if that makes any sense

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool see the updated answer. Using `new Date().getTime()` to get the unix timestamp now..

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but you have some issue with your code such as an undefined function `microtime`.

I've replaced `microtime` with a simple counter for the purpose of the example:

```js
var increment = getNumber();
var input = document.getElementById('displaynum');

var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  input.value = increment();
}, 1000);

function getNumber() {
  var x = 0;
  return function() {
    return x++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="displaynum" type="text" />
```

Comment: I really like this code, and it tracks the number sequentially. Is there a way to continue the count indefinitely? or only when the browser is open?

Comment: The program above will increment indefinitely since there is no condition in the code telling it to stop. Since this code runs in a web browser, it will be terminated when the browser is closed.

Comment: If you're interested in the technique used to create the counter then you should read up on javascript closures: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp